# Stack Overflow in ES, PT, RU, JP have mixed-language descriptions

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, stack-exchange-button, internationalization

The international Stack Overflow sites in Spanish, Portuguese, Russian, and Japanese seem to have a bug in their quick site descriptions (under their titles), for they all start with the word

> For...

*in English, instead of their respective languages*

As an example, the Spanish Stack Overflow site description is:

> *For* programadores y profesionales de la informática

Obviously, this isn't something too big of a deal, but since they offer those sites in their respective languages, it would be nice if this issue were fixed.

You can see this under "More communities" in the top bar.

> [image]

You can also see this on the [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#name) page, where the descriptions begin with

> Q&A for...

> [image]

Comment: [Related question](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3680/176217) in meta.ruSO for mobile web and android app.

Answer (score 9):

The first issue (for a top bar) is done now:

> [image: top bar SO]

But the rest (on stackexhange site list) still is an issue.

Answer (score 8):

The descriptions on the [Site List](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) have been updated.

See below for the changes.

[image]