# Problem with translations at moved question

Tags: bug, migration, localization, translations, site-description

One question was moved from ruSO to enSO and after moving I saw this incorrect translation:

> [image]

This problem earlier occured in other places: [Stack Overflow in ES, PT, RU, JP have mixed-language descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286603/stack-overflow-in-es-pt-ru-jp-have-mixed-language-descriptions)

Link to my Stack Overflow in Russian Meta question: [Ошибка в переводе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/)

Comment: AFAIK the general consensus was not to migrate questions posted in the wrong language, but let the OP repost it on the correct site. That would prevent this problem from happening in the first place :)

Comment: What about questions migrated from a localised site to that site's meta?

Comment: about what you are saying?

Comment: The problem is that the text *This question cam from our site for ${sitename}* is only generated once and then stored with the post, IIRC. I expect this to be status-bydesign.

Comment: @rene, you mean this not a bug but a feature? :-D

Comment: @Grundy it certainly is. Not sure why that is funny ;)

Comment: Another day, another [tag:status-bugdesign].