# Change taglines for non-English sites and new Meta sites on SEDE homepage

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, localization, international-sites

The homepage of the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) has mixed-language taglines for non-English sites; e.g. for Russian Stack Overflow it is "Q&A for программистов".

[image: listing for Russian Stack Overflow on SEDE homepage]

Can this be changed to something that is completely in the language at hand, like what has already been done [a while ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313585/295232) for the [list of all sites on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites):

[image: Stack Exchange site list]

---

A similar problem: while older per-site meta sites, e.g. Meta Stack Overflow, have a separate tagline:

[image: listing for Meta Stack Overflow on SEDE homepage]

newer ones have the same tagline as their main site counterparts:

[image: listing for EOS.IO Meta & Tezos Meta on SEDE homepage]

Comment: There are now a couple of pending changes that needs an update of single rows in  the Sites table in the Data.StackExchange database. I'll add this one to that list ... some of those changes are beyond the 6 to 8 weeks timeline so don't hold your breath ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These should be fixed. I just ran several update statements to correct the Tagline for both the main and meta international sites.

Answer (score 9):

This needs an update of the Sites table in the Data.StackExchange database. As there is no maintenance UI this needs someone with DB access to run the following script (after they got amended with the correct Russian text):

```
use [Data.StackExchange]
-- ru.SO
update sites set tagline ='Вопросы и ответы для программистов' where id = 275  -- main site
-- ru.MSO
update sites set tagline ='Вопросы и ответы по работе сайта Stack Overflow на русском' where id = 276  -- meta site
```

<sub>Meta text kindly provided by [Grundy](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51345877#51345877)</sub>

The Id's (275 and 276 in this case) are coming from the [`/sites`](https://data.stackexchange.com/sites) endpoint. The results do come from a plain select of the Sites table, shown [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L51).

Comment: Спасибо. Where are those site IDs coming from? They're neither in the `sys.databases` table, nor in the [site switcher source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/topbar/site-switcher/all-pinnable-sites).

Comment: @Glorfindel added that to the amswer